# Crear múltiples tarjetas con contenidos diferentes del menú select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Hola espero me puedan ayudar.
Necesito que al seleccionar en el menu `select` "numero 1" ó "numero 2".

```
<select>
  <option>numero 1</option>
  <option>numero 2</option>
</select>
```

Que pase a las cartas y así agregar múltiples cartas con contenido del "option" diferentes "numero 1" ó "numero 2"

```js
var card = [

];

(function newcards(card) {

  this.init = function() {
    this.generateList();
    this.enterUser();
  };

  this.generateList = function() {

    var parent = document.querySelector(".contenido");
    var template = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {

      template += '<div class="col-sm-4">';
      template += '<div class="card animated bounceInRight">';
      template += '<div class="card-delete" data-card="' + i + '">x</div>';
      template += '<div class="card-block">';
      template += '<div id="ejemplo"></div>';
      template += '<h3 class="card-title">' + card[i].name + '</h3>';
      template += '</div>';
      template += '</div>';
      template += '</div>';
    }
    parent.innerHTML = '';
    parent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', template);
    deleteCard();
  };
  this.enterUser = function() {
    function grabUser() {
      var name = document.querySelector('#user_name').value;
      var elements = [name];
      if (validateUser(elements)) {
        document.querySelector('#myForm').reset();
        card.push({
          name: name
        });
        generateList();
      } else {
        document.querySelector('#error').style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.querySelector('#error').style.display = 'none';
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
    document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      grabUser();
    });
  };
  this.validateUser = function(inputs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i] == '') {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
  this.deleteCard = function() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".card-delete");

    function deleteThis(element) {
      var obj = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-card'));
      card.splice(obj, 1);
      generateList();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        deleteThis(this);
      })
    };
  };
  this.init();
})(card);
var opciones = document.getElementById('opciones');

document.getElementById('boton')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    $("#ejemplo").html(opciones.value);
  });
```

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.card-block {
  margin: 1em;
}

.card-text {
  color: #00BCD4;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#error {
  display: none;
}

.card-delete {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 6px;
  line-height: 9px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #F44336;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-container">
    <form id="myForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" placeholder="Escribe lo que sea">
      </div>

      <select id="opciones">
        <option>número 1</option>
        <option>número 2</option>
        <option>número 3</option>
        <option>número 4</option>
      </select>

      <input type="submit" id="boton" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Agregar Carta">
      <p class="text-danger" id="error">Completa Los Campos</p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="row contenido">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1- ¿Que debe suceder si escribo 'Hola' en el `input`, tengo seleccionado `número 2` y presiono el botón agregar carta? 2-¿Donde se vera reflejado el resultado deseado?

Comment: Mira al escribir Hola y agregar carta este hola se vera en la carta y puedes agregar otra carta con otro texto diferente y no eliminara la carta anterior. Lo que necesito agregar es por ejemplo: cuando le de en numero 2 del menú select ese mismo texto "numero 2" se coloque en la tarjeta y no se elimine o cambie cundo yo cree otra tarjeta con otro select por ejemplo "numero 4" y la anterior siga en numero 2.

Comment: @OrielC. no le agregues solucionado a tu pregunta, así no funciona este lugar, ya aceptaste la respuesta que te dió solución y con eso basta

Comment: @shadow ok Disculpa soy nuevo y estaba desesperado por esta solución ya que no podía avanzar en mi proyecto. Un Saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agregué las siguientes líneas a la function grabUser, ubicarlas antes de **var elements = [name]**

```js
// Referencia al Select
let elOpt = document.getElementById('opciones');
// Obtenemos el texto de la opción seleccionada
selectedText = elOpt.options[elOpt.selectedIndex].text;
// Obteneros el valor de la opción seleccionada
selectedValue = elOpt.options[elOpt.selectedIndex].value;
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```js
function grabUser() {
    var name = document.querySelector('#user_name').value;

    // Referencia al Select
    let elOpt = document.getElementById('opciones');
    // Obtenemos el texto de la opción seleccionada
    selectedText = elOpt.options[elOpt.selectedIndex].text;
    // Obteneros el valor de la opción seleccionada
    selectedValue = elOpt.options[elOpt.selectedIndex].value;   

    var elements = [name];
    if (validateUser(elements)) {
        document.querySelector('#myForm').reset();

        card.push({
            name: name
        });

        generateList();
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#error').style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector('#error').style.display = 'none';
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

1.- Si lo que deseas es mostrar el texto de la opción seleccionada en el card, reemplaza

```js
card.push({
    name: name
});
```

Por

```js
card.push({
    name: selectedText
});
```

2.- Si lo que deseas es itinerar en base al valor de la opción seleccionada, importante agregar el atributo value al select.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < selectedValue; i++) {
    card.push({
        name: selectedText
    });
}
```

Comment: hola MVPFrans, gracias por responder pero para que la respuesta sea de calidad no basta con pegar el codigo, has tambien de explicar su funcionamiento. un saludo !

Comment: Hola Creo que no funciona así, ya que al seleccionar numero 4 salen los 4 pero al seleccionar nuevamente 1, se eliminan los 4 anteriores y tengo ya escrito un código donde quiero ir agregando información de los input y lo único que me falta es la del select que no logro configurar el script

Comment: Esto es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Gracias!